# Альтернатива Stream.DataAvaiable в SSLStream C#

Tags: c#, ssl, tcp

Я пишу простой чат на tcp,
я уже сделал отправку и прием сообщений,
решил переделать в защищенную версию,
сделал простое криптографическое шифрование,
но, хочу еще ssl шифрование (для улучшения навыков работы с ssl)
сделать.
вот код:

```
do
{
    bytes = Stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

    builder.Append(CryptCl.Decrypt(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, 
    bytes), SecretKey)); 
}
    while (Stream.DataAvailable);
```

не обращайте внимания на

```
CryptCl.Decrypt()
```

Comment: Такого аналога нет. Базовый класс Stream и вся архитектура классов, которые используют его, устроены так, что это свойство не нужно в общем случае. Просто вызывайте Read и ждите, пока что-то появится

Comment: А можно оставить Stream.DataAviable

Comment: Такого свойства нет в базовом классе, оно только в NetworkStream